# Is it possible to create survfit and survdiff objects using imputed data?

Tags: survival, cox-model, multiple-imputation, kaplan-meier

I have a dataset in which 45% of participants have missing data. Given the high proportion of missingness, I planned to conduct survival analyses on both an imputed and non-imputed dataset.

I am confident the data are MAR and have used the mice package in R to impute the missing values. I have found it easy enough to create a pooled Cox regression model, using the with() and pool() functions.

I would now like to create survfit and survdiff objects for the construction of Kaplan-Meier curves, but cannot find a way to perform this in R. As an example, if I use the following code:

```
pathsurv <- with(data = imputed_adenosurv,survfit (Surv (newos, newcensored) ~ pathology))

pathsurv <- with (data = imputed_adenosurv, survdiff(Surv(newos, newcensored) ~ pathology))
```

I simply get a list with the results of 45 different imputations. Using the pool() function does not rectify this.

Would appreciate any help that can be offered :)

Answer (score 1):

The `survdiff()` and `survfit()` functions don't seem to return estimates of coefficients and coefficient-covariance matrices in a form that the `pool()` function in `mice` can readily use. You can apply Rubin's rules to get pooled estimates including variances, following the principles in Stef van Buuren's [book](https://stefvanbuuren.name/fimd).

**`survdiff()`**

An object returned by the `survdiff()` function with the default log-rank test contains the numbers of observed and expected (under the null hypothesis) events for each stratum, in the `obs` and `exp` slots respectively. The `var` slot contains the corresponding covariance matrix. If there are N strata there are only N-1 independent contributions to `obs-exp`, so one stratum needs to be removed for the statistical test, which is a multi-parameter [Wald test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wald_test#Test(s)_on_multiple_parameters) of the null hypothesis that all of the remaining `obs-exp` values are 0.

[Section 5.3.1](https://stefvanbuuren.name/fimd/sec-multiparameter.html#sec:wald) of van Buuren's book shows how to pool such estimates. A Wald statistic is calculated from the imputation-adjusted pooled covariance matrix (see [Section 2.3.2](https://stefvanbuuren.name/fimd/sec-whyandwhen.html#sec:threesources)), then evaluated in an F-test having degrees of freedom based on the number of imputations, the number of coefficients, and the fraction of missing information.

The `D1()` function in `mice` implements this. I'm not sure how to get the `survdiff()` output into the needed form. "Any R expression produced by `expression()` can be evaluated on the multiply imputed data," however ([Section 5.1.4](https://stefvanbuuren.name/fimd/workflow.html#sec:repeated)). One might write an expression to put the needed (linearly independent) `obs-exp` and covariance estimates from the `survdiff()` models into a format that the [broom](https://broom.tidymodels.org/) package can interpret to extract model components for `pool()`. (See the documentation for `pool()`.) I don't have any experience with that, however.

**`survfit()`**

The pooled Kaplan-Meier curves would be the averages of the individual curves, by stratum. The object returned by `survfit()` contains standard errors for each event time point, of the type that was specified in the function call. To get closer to the normality assumed by Rubin's rules, choose the `log` (default) or the `log-log` type, apply Rubin's rules to pool at each time point, then re-transform back to the survival scale.